# Nested json data into a data table using python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a json file like below..

```
{
"assetPropertyValues" : {
    "A001234": {
        "PV": 1.2345
    },
    "A001235": {
        "PV": 1.234678
    },
    "A001236": {
        "PV": 1.234678
    }
 }
}
```

I want to display this data as below..

```
                 PV
A001234          1.2345
A001235          1.2345678
A001236          1.2345678
```

i don't have any idea how to do this..please help me out..
Thank you..

Comment: SO requires you to first work on the problem yourself and not just post the exercises directly. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Yes sir..I have tried that problem using json_normalize() and I went through some videos and documents..I didn't get the answer like this..I should have post that output too..as this is my first question posting in stack over flow , I don't know how to post..I will make it better from the next time.. thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) and `orient='index'`:

```
v = {
    "assetPropertyValues": {
        "A001234": {
            "PV": 1.2345
        },
        "A001235": {
            "PV": 1.234678
        },
        "A001236": {
            "PV": 1.234678
        }
    }
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v['assetPropertyValues'], orient='index')
```

Or when reading from a file with [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load):

```
import json

import pandas as pd

with open('source.json') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        json.load(f)['assetPropertyValues'],
        orient='index'
    )
```

`df`:

```
               PV
A001234  1.234500
A001235  1.234678
A001236  1.234678
```